# PHP Output Words Not In String

Tags: php, compare, words

I have two strings:

```
$string = shell_exec('reg.bat '.$arg); //returns word\0word\0word
$stringA = "$string";
$stringB = "word,other,word2,other2";
$array1 = explode('\0', $stringA);
$array2 = explode(',', $stringB);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

I can use array_diff to find the differences, but the last word shows up as not in both strings even though it is because of the \0 delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$stringA = "word,other,word2,other";
$stringB = "word,other,word2,other2";

$array1 = explode(',', $stringA);
$array2 = explode(',', $stringB);

$result = array_diff($array2, $array1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => other2
)
```

**More Info:**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

Explode the string to an array and have a look at the [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function.

Comment: Try switching the arguments when calling array_diff().

Comment: What if the words aren't in the same order in both strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_diff and str_word_count:

```
print_r(
    array_diff(
        str_word_count("word\0word\0word", 1, '0123456789'),
        str_word_count("word,other,word2,other2", 1, '0123456789'))
);
// will return an empty array, because "word" is in "word,other,word2,other2"
```

Or switch the input around:

```
print_r(
    array_diff(
        str_word_count("word,other,word2,other2", 1, '0123456789'),
        str_word_count("word\0word\0word", 1, '0123456789'))
);
// will return an array containing "other", "word2", "other"
```

Comment: I think I was able to get this to work, but I have another problem.

In the first string that I compare, the words are separated by \0 instead of a comma.

I used this to add commas, but the string still isn't being processed the same as if I manually typed "word,word,word":

$string = str_replace("\\0",",",$string);
$string = "$string";

How can I format the string with commas and get it to process the same way as $stringB?

Comment: @John if they are like this `'word\0other\0word2\0other2'` then all you have to change is the quotes so it reads `"word\0other\0word2\0other2"` - with single quotes the strings wont be treated as null characters, but backslash zero.

Comment: Because of that \0, the array_diff function is outputting the last word in my array even though it is in both strings. What I can do about the last word in word\0word\0word ?

Comment: @John can you please update the question accordingly, so others have a chance to adjust their codes, too? Also, I dont understand what you are saying. If you use double quotes, the above will output "other2", which is the only word that is not present in both word lists.